# User edit war ending up with spoilers in title and all over StackExchange

Tags: discussion, editing

### Should there be an edit and flag for mods in same action?

I have tried to let this user know that his question title is featured and all over StackExchange people who may have not finished all the books currently released who may have gotten hints that the title is a spoiler.  I have done like this question asked and edited it ([Is it okay to have spoilers in question titles?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/835/is-it-okay-to-have-spoilers-in-question-titles)) but the OP continues to be stubborn and revert the edits out of pride.

I am not going to keep playing games but I flagged the user and the question but no interventions have occurred yet and he continues down the same path.  Now I feel like giving up so what else can be done to prevent this?

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/71504/revisions

Answer (score 8):

What you can do, and I've done this for the question you mention is "flag for moderator attention".

- Click on the 'flag' button:

[image: Flag Button]

- You will then be presented with the following options:

[image]

- Choose the last option.
- Give the moderators a description of what is going on.

  - I said something like "There's an 'Edit War' going on here."...
- The Mods will then have the ability to lock the question (or do whatever is necessary).

Comment: Thanks, I actually did that already but it appears the same behavior continued.

Comment: It is a new question, my guesses are that the Mods haven't had a chance to look at it yet...

Comment: @Mooz What Mooz said.

Comment: @Keen Looks like he changed it right back today.