# Is there a way from keeping GoT spoilers out of the Hot Network Questions?

Tags: feature-request, spoilers, hot-network-questions

Is there any sensible way to stop questions whose titles spoil information about new *Game of Thrones* episodes from appearing in the hot network questions?
Not everyone has seen the last episode.

Comment: Download [SOX](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox). Tick "Hide the Hot Network Questions module". Done

Comment: Technically, we already have a policy against spoilers in titles. The problem is new users and getting them fixed up quickly.

Comment: [We already try to avoid spoilers in titles](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/835/21267) and given how popular Game of Thrones is, most questions are likely to hit the HNQ, and there's literally nothing we can do about that!

Comment: @Möoz No I'm asking whether it's possible to prevent them from showing up in the HNQ list. But if there's literally nothing you can do about that, that would be the answer to my question.

Comment: Here's a [GreaseMonkey script to hide the HNQ](https://gist.github.com/phantom42/0a13b6a0b77becb8d0a15da20a8ef4ec)

Comment: @phantom42 see [my update](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11193/19561) to your script.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62944/discussion-on-question-by-sgf-is-there-a-way-from-keeping-got-spoilers-out-of-th).

Comment: For bonus points, could we have an option for hiding GoT questions for UK users on Mondays? New episodes are broadcast here at 2am, and I'm sure I'm not the only one who religiously tries to avoid spoilers until I've had a chance to watch the episode after work. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've adjusted [the HNQ Hider by Phantom42](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11186/can-you-guys-stop-spoiling-game-of-thrones-in-the-hot-network-questions#comment35380_11186) a bit to hide only HNQs from this stack.

Hiding M&TV as well is left as an exercise for the reader.
(Hint: the class you want for that is `favicon-movies`).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        HNQ SciFi  Hider
// @description Hides SciFi in the Stackexchange HNQ

// @include /^https?:\/\/(.*\.)?stackoverflow\.com/.*$/
// @include /^https?:\/\/(.*\.)?serverfault\.com/.*$/
// @include /^https?:\/\/(.*\.)?superuser\.com/.*$/
// @include /^https?:\/\/(.*\.)?stackexchange\.com/.*$/
// @include /^https?:\/\/(.*\.)?askubuntu\.com/.*$/
// @include /^https?:\/\/(.*\.)?mathoverflow\.com/.*$/
// @include /^https?:\/\/discuss\.area51\.stackexchange\.com/.*$/
// @include /^https?:\/\/stackapps\.com/.*$/

// @require     https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
$('#hot-network-questions ul li div.favicon-scifi').parent().hide();
```

Comment: Cool. Mine was just something I whipped up last night in a few minutes just to see how easy it might be.

Comment: Do you really need all those regex in the includes. I swear you can just use wildcards ("*")

Comment: You don't. Mine used wildcards. I just didn't do all the other sister-sites with custom urls because I was lazy.

Comment: I've gone and posted this on a relevant [main meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300344/278659), crediting you both (SQB and @phantom42).

Comment: @Randal'Thor great!

Answer (score 7):

We try to avoid spoilers in titles already, per site policy. However, what's considered a spoiler varies person to person. We run into the issue of people not wanting spoilers blocking the tag for awhile, so only people OK with or lenient towards spoilers see questions to edit them.

We don't have control over what's HNQ outside of what the masses happen to vote or answer on to trigger the HNQ algorithm. We really can't help that. Ignoring tags on our stack, such as [game-of-thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones), won't hide it from HNQ, either.

The best advice I can give you is to just assume they're about older events. We get plenty of questions about previous seasons. That, or just don't let it get to you (there's some research that spoilers can increase your enjoyment, actually!)

I don't watch GoT, but I do know a surprising amount about the show just from news headlines and posts. The number of times Jon Snow has filled my news feed is frustrating (I don't even know what he looks like). I feel like HNQ may be the least of your worries!

I have had the Internet spoil some key The Walking Dead and Doctor Who moments for me, so I understand it happens. I've just started rolling with it and focusing more on the parts that headlines don't talk about.

I wish there were more we could do, but I do think we do about all we can.

Perhaps if we're lucky, someone can make a browser extension to hide HNQ questions based on Stack...

### [...Oh, hey, someone *did*!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11193/31178)

Comment: See my answer for a HNQ-per-stack-hider.